# How can I access typed emits from a Vue component when using extend?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

I have 2 search components that function very similarly.
They both emitters and have the same props, refs and watchers.

I have been able to successfully access the props by using defineComponent in the component that is extending the base component. However, I am unable to access the emits with the correct types. (or use the ref or watcher.)

I am trying to replicate extend, which was in Vue 2. As both components function so similarly, it seems superfluous to duplicate the code in both places.

Example code below:
Base component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

import type { OptionType } from './BaseSearch.types'

export interface SearchEmits {
    (event: 'update:modelValue', val: OptionType[]): void
    (event: 'input', val: string): void
}

const emit = defineEmits<SearchEmits>()

const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
        closeOnSelect?: boolean
        disabled?: boolean
        errorMessage?: string
        isError?: boolean
        isLoading?: boolean
        label?: string
        modelValue: OptionType[]
        options: OptionType[]
        placeholder?: string
        required?: boolean
        searchable?: boolean
    }>(),
    {
        required: false,
        searchable: true,
    }
)

const input = ref('')

watch(input, () => {
    emit('input', input.value)
})
</script>
```

Search component extending the base

```
<template>
(I have omitted the template as I don't believe it's relevant)
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import MultiSelect from 'MultiSelect'
import BaseSearch, { SearchEmits } from '../BaseSearch/BaseSeach.vue'

export default defineComponent({
    components: { Multiselect },
    extends: BaseSearch,
    props: {
        // extends baseSearchProps
        canClear: {
            required: false,
            type: Boolean,
        },
    },
    setup(props, ctx) {
        const emit: SearchEmits = ctx.emit

        //ideally access this ref from the baseSearch
        const input = ref('')
        //ideally use watcher from the baseSearch
        watch(input, () => {
            emit('input', input.value)
        })

        return { emit, highlightMatchedTerm, input, props }
    },
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but the problem might be you're specifying `setup()` on the extension. This might actually replace the `setup()` function of the extended one (which is pretty much the contents of `<script setup>` in your case). But I could also be wrong. Possible approaches: a) use Options API in the extension to make your alterations; b) ask on vue-3-advanced channel on Vue's discord. Core Vue team members rarely answer on [SO]. Once you do get an answer, it would be good to post it here, where it would be much better indexed, therefore more useful for the common vue folk.